# Use of BorshSchema trait

Tags: rust, serialization, deserialization, schema, borsh

I'd like to ensure I understand why you would implement the `BorshSchema` trait of the [borsh](https://crates.io/crates/borsh) crate.

[Docs](https://docs.rs/borsh-v/latest/borsh/schema/index.html)

If I have it right, its use is when you have a blob and you don't know the schema, but you know that the blob starts with a schema, and you proceed to deserialize the initial bytes of the blob into a `BorshSchemaContainer` [type](https://docs.rs/borsh/latest/borsh/schema/struct.BorshSchemaContainer.html) (or equivalent in another language). *After this you may then define your deser target type in your language and then can deserialize the remainder of the blob*?